# Linear Model Question Evaluate Expectation

Tags: linear-algebra

$y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, with $e\sim N(0, \sigma^2 I)$. $X$ has full rank with $\operatorname{rank}(X)=k$.
Evaluate $E[(y'Ay-\sigma^2)^2]$

for $A=\frac{1}{m-k+2}(I-X(X'X)^{-1}X')$,

where $y$ is $m \times 1$, $X$ is $k \times 1$ and $B$ is $k \times 1$

**My thoughts**:
Let $B=y'Ay-\sigma^2$, then $E(B^2)=E(B'B)$. I am not sure how to simply it further from here. I don't think I can make $E(B'B)=E(B')E(B)$ because of independence.

I know the distribution of $e$ implies $Y$ is distributed normally with the same mean and variance.
I know $E(y'Ay)=\operatorname{tr}(A \operatorname{var}(Y))+E(y)'AE(y)$ Generally from theorem.
- in this case I think it is $\operatorname{tr}(A\sigma^2 I)$. ( Don't know if this is useful though)

The squared term makes me think of a chi square distribution, but I can't think of any theorem to apply...

Any hints in the right direction or similar examples would be greatly appreciated!